# Where can I find old versions of openssh-server (particularly 7.2, before patch)?

Tags: apt, openssh, source-packages

I'm trying to demonstrate `openssh-server` (7.2) DDOS exploit attack. When I did `apt-get` update or when checked at [ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssh-server) both show only the patched versions. I'm not sure where to find the original package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download whatever version of OpenSSH you are interested in from the [official website of the project](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html#http). OpenSSH 7.2 can be found for example here:

```
http://mirrors.dalenys.com/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.2p1.tar.gz
```

You need to build it from the source, but it should not be a problem.

Comment: Also always verify signatures